# Open modal on mouse position

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

```js
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
items.forEach(fe);

function fe(item, index){
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
  item.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('show');
});
  
}
```

```css
.horizontal-scrollable{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #d2d2d2;
     overflow-x:auto;
     max-width: 450px;
}
 .item {
     background-color: #a29f9b;
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 0 5px;
     cursor:pointer;
     position:relative;
}
 .item2{
     min-width:500px 
}
 .item3{
     min-width:700px 
}
 .modal{
     display:none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     right: 0;
     background: #4977d0;
     z-index: 100;
}
 .modal.show{
     display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scrollable">
  <div class="item item1">
    <h1>Item 1</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    <h1>Item 3</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item4">
    <h1>Item 4</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code snippet, If you click on any item, then it will show a `modal` on the right side. As you can see, `item 3` is larger in width. So if you click on `item 3` then you have to `scroll-right` to view the modal.

So I want to show modal on mouse click position.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There are at least two options

- The first one will spawn the modal directly at the mouse position using JS
- And the second one will spawn the modal on the left side. This can be achieved using CSS

### First option

So basically you can get the mouse position and set the modal position to it.
In detail remove the top/left/right/bottom properties from the modal class in CSS (they aren't needed) and add some lines of JS.
Please write me in the comments if you want to align the modal a bit around the mouse cursor... It's just about a few numbers.

```js
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
items.forEach(fe);

var mousePos = {};

function fe(item, index){
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect(); // get some poition, scale,... properties of the item
    mousePos.x = e.clientX - rect.left; // get the mouse position relative to the element
    mousePos.y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    item.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('show');
    item.querySelector('.modal').style.left = mousePos.x + "px"; // set the modal position to the last stored position
    item.querySelector('.modal').style.top = mousePos.y + "px";
  });
}
```

```css
.horizontal-scrollable{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #d2d2d2;
     overflow-x:auto;
     max-width: 450px;
}
 .item {
     background-color: #a29f9b;
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 0 5px;
     cursor:pointer;
     position: relative;
}
 .item2{
     min-width:500px 
}
 .item3{
     min-width:700px 
}
 .modal{
     display:none;
     position: absolute;
     background: #4977d0;
     z-index: 100;
}
 .modal.show{
     display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scrollable">
  <div class="item item1">
    <h1>Item 1</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    <h1>Item 3</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item4">
    <h1>Item 4</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Second option

The second option uses basic CSS to align the modals on the left side - it is much easier to implement and you just have to remove thee left/right/top/bottom property from the modal class and add `left:0`:

```js
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
items.forEach(fe);

var mousePos = {};

function fe(item, index){
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    item.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('show');
  });
}
```

```css
.horizontal-scrollable{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #d2d2d2;
     overflow-x:auto;
     max-width: 450px;
}
 .item {
     background-color: #a29f9b;
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 0 5px;
     cursor:pointer;
     position: relative;
}
 .item2{
     min-width:500px 
}
 .item3{
     min-width:700px 
}
 .modal{
     display:none;
     position: absolute;
     background: #4977d0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 100;
}
 .modal.show{
     display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scrollable">
  <div class="item item1">
    <h1>Item 1</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    <h1>Item 3</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item4">
    <h1>Item 4</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope I could help :D

Comment: Thanks for your second option. But it is not required as my feature. Most, thanks for the first option !!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style dynamically and get the position X of your controller, then add the style using JS code.
Also, remove the right 0 from your modal class

```js
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
items.forEach(fe);

function fe(item, index){
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  item.querySelector('.modal').style.left = e.clientX + "px";
  item.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('show');
});
  
}
```

```css
.horizontal-scrollable{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #d2d2d2;
     overflow-x:auto;
     max-width: 450px;
}
 .item {
     background-color: #a29f9b;
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 0 5px;
     cursor:pointer;
     position:relative;
}
 .item2{
     min-width:500px 
}
 .item3{
     min-width:700px 
}
 .modal{
     display:none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     background: #4977d0;
     z-index: 100;
}
 .modal.show{
     display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scrollable">
  <div class="item item1">
    <h1>Item 1</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    <h1>Item 3</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item4">
    <h1>Item 4</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <p>I am modal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working if I click on right edge of the item.